# Keep Temp Data For Each User

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to know what is the best way to keep data such as simple ID for each user if I won't use `Session` in ASP.Net and ASP.Net MVC applications?

Comment: Use ​​​cookies.

Comment: There's also `localStorage` with HTML5.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, But there is another question, I know this is not a place to ask but I try to avoid OP. What are the disadvantages of using Session in MVC applications?

Comment: The same as Asp.Net.  Session is a tool.  If the tool fits your needs use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use cookies or if it is just the ID of the currently authenticated user, the [`Forms Authentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) cookie seems exactly designed for this purpose. The forms authentication cookie could be extended and add some other custom user info that you might need on each request (such as the First and Last name of the user). This would avoid you to hit the database on each request. You could use the UserData portion of the Forms Authentication cookie.

Answer (score 4):

You could store it in the user profile, this can be extended by inheriting from ProfileBase and you can implement your own properties.

For example:

```
public class ProfileManager : ProfileBase
{
public ProfileManager() : base()
{

}

[SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
[ProfileProvider("AspNetSqlProfileProvider")]
public string DisplayName {
    get
    {
        return base["DisplayName"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        base["DisplayName"] = value;
        this.Save();
    }
}
}
```

In your config, you need to tell your application what type your profile is of:

```
<profile inherits="ProfileNamespace.ProfileManager" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" enabled="true">
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</providers>
</profile>
```